# Is it possible with JQuery to have one image fade out & another fade in on top of each other without having to mess with their positioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I think the best way to demonstrate this is with a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/75wczrw7/4/). As you may notice from this example, the first image does fade out as the second one fades in, but the second image also pushes the first image down. After that, the image that is currently displayed will instantly disappear when the next image starts to fade in. Also, StackOverflow demands code with jsfiddle links, so here's my HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img width="400px" src="https://consumermediallc.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/totinos-stock-08-2014.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="https://36.media.tumblr.com/66fa7962b68e90da541078fcc9efdc25/tumblr_inline_nnby3oQs8s1si7eaa_500.jpg" alt="Lightning Ghost" />
    <img src="http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2014-05/enhanced/webdr02/14/7/enhanced-3829-1400068353-2.jpg" alt="Girraffe-dog" />
    <img src="https://www.colourbox.com/preview/2291250-terrible-grimace-men-with-shovel.jpg" alt="Purpleish Kitty" />
</div><!--slideshow-->
```

and here's my JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    //make the div take up the space given
    $('div#slideshow').width('100%');
    //make each slide fits within that div easily
    $("div#slideshow > img").width("60%");
    //hide the first image
    $('#slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        //put each slide up for six seconds and cause it to fade out while the
        //new one fades in over a period of two seconds
        $('#slideshow :first-child').fadeTo(2000, 0)
            .next('img').fadeTo(2000, 1).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
    }, 6000);
});
```

I want the images to transition on top of each other evenly, but I want to do that without modifying the CSS position style properties of the parent div and it's images. The reason I don't like formatting the images to have the `position:absolute` property is because it separates the slideshow from the webpage. I don't like having to reposition the slideshow *every* time I change something on my webpage. I greatly appreciate any help you can give, even if you can clarify that what I'm asking for is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this CSS.  I know that you didn't want to use positioning but there is no way around it.  However,  by setting position:relative on the #slideshow div the img elements are absolutely positioned relative to the #slideshow container which means you can move the #slideshow container anywhere and the img elements will follow.

## slidshow{

```
position: relative;
```

}

## slideshow img{

```
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
```

}

Here is the modified fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/75wczrw7/5/